# Help with Anydice function for 3d10 dice pool

Tags: dice, statistics, anydice

I'd like to see the probability distribution for 3d10 being rolled, where the highest number is positive, the lowest (closest to 1) is negative, and the middle die is ignored. (As a way of providing "advantage" dice in a 2d10 over/under die rolling mechanic.) I've tried to look into programming it myself in Anydice but can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to subtract the lowest of the 3d10 from the highest, use this:

```
function: xx A:s xx {
result:1@A - 3@A
}
output [xx 3d10 xx]
```

[Here's a link.](http://anydice.com/program/b2b9)

As the function expects a sequence, it evaluates for all possible rolls when it gets dice as input.

Comment: @LegendaryDude There should be no negative values. You subtract a smaller positive integer from a larger one. I understood that we should only roll once and use that and not mix two rolls.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Yes it is how it works. I just did it! And yes, the question is not clear it seems.

Comment: Oh sorry; you're right.  It didn't occur to me that the lowest of set A could be higher than the highest of set B when set A and set B are two separate 3d10 rolls.  Clearly I am not thinking correctly about the problem.  I have deleted my answer and defer to you.  :)

Comment: That is an impressive application of anydice. I hope you don't mind, I copied the function and made a link of it to add to the answer.